# Elixir using ExActor is there a way to hibernate depending on conditions

Tags: elixir

I am currently learning Elixir to develop an auction web site. So I have a worker for each auction, when the worker is started it might go to hibernate immediatly, but during the last N minutes before the end of the auction I don't want my worker to hibernate each time a bid is received (tell me if I am wrong but it might not be efficient).

I have started developing with basic GenServer OTP (handle_call, handle_info ...) and I am refactoring with ExActor and Fsm (both from Saša Jurić), and trying to apply CQRS/ES.

Is there a way to achieve this using ExActor and not going back to handle_call "basics" ?

I would like to achieve something similar to :

`{:reply, ...}` when there is less than 10 minutes left until the auction's end.

`{:reply, ..., :hibernate}` when there is more than 10 minutes left until the auction's end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Erlang, hibernation does following things:

- discard process call stack
- do garbage collection
- after that, process memory might be reduced to values lower than minimal heap size
- process wakes on message (if there are messages in mailbox, it wakes immediately)
- on waking up, there is another garbage collection, that restores normal process size

Hibernation and waking up is quite CPU intensive and saves really small amounts of memory. My advice is to either not use it at all or make some performance tests to see, if the gain is worth it. If you have millions of auction processes and they get new messages rarely, there might be some memory gain, but don't expect anything big.

You can very easily switch between hibernate depending on conditions. It is enough to write something like this in normal OTP:

```
case time_left > ten_minutes do
  true -> {:reply, new_state, :hibernate}
  false -> {:reply, new_state}
end
```

In ExActor it would be:

```
defcall your_funcion(args), state: state, do
  ...
  case time_left > ten_minutes do
    true -> set_and_reply(new_state, :hibernate)
    false -> set_and_reply(new_state, timeout)
  end
end
```

Macros like `reply` take optional argument, that is either timeout value or `:hibernate` atom.

PS.
You might be interested in article about [real time bidding in Erlang](http://ferd.ca/rtb-where-erlang-blooms.html).